# Embed screenshots in cucumber jvm with base64

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to display my captured screenshots on my extent report using cucumber jvm. The problem i have is that .embed only takes the byte[] which stores the image locally. I'm trying to share this report and i've seen some solutions for ruby but not much for Java. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my current implementation.

I'm also trying to store all the images in a test folder created after every test run.

```
        public static void embedScreenshotInReport(Scenario scenario){

        if(scenario.isFailed()){

        String folderExt = baseUtility.getTodayDate();
        String destin = baseUtility.createTestFolder(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/screenshots/"+folderExt);

        String dest = destin+scenario+".png";

        try{
            String base64Screenshot = null;
            TakesScreenshot tsDriver;
            tsDriver = (TakesScreenshot) getDriver();
            base64Screenshot = tsDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);                     

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

            byte[] decodeScreenshot = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Screenshot.getBytes());
            out.write(decodeScreenshot);
            scenario.embed(decodeScreenshot, "image/png");
            out.close();

        }
```

Comment: I just want to understand this more clearly, if your 
`format={"json:cucumber.json"}` 
then you have screenshot embedded, isn't it? where you can share your JSON file freely and upon converting JSON to html you'll see your screenshots unwrapped, isn't it?

Beware that embedding screenshot will make your JVM cry running out of heap-space memory. Be wise and switch to embedding links of your screenshots with relative path like:

`String links = "<a href=\"..\\Screenshots\" + scenario.png + ">" + scenario.getName() +"<";
//add more links if you want
scenario.write(links);`

Comment: I am actually using com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter in my runner class so i'm not converting to JSON format. This is because i'm trying to generate a user friendly report. Unfortunately, i can either embed with cucumber scenario or store the file in a different folder